# list the month with no data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

The current query work perfect the problem is there is no data for the current month (April) so it does not list the month as 0, How do I get it to list the month as having 0 interivews?

QUERY

```
select distinct from_unixtime(interv_date,'%M %Y') AS month, count(*) as totals
from " . TABLE_PREFIX . "interviews
group by month
order by interv_date desc
limit 6
```

NOTE that the interv_date column is a epoch timestamp (example: 1428003691)

PHP

```
<table class=\"highchart\" data-graph-container=\"#graphcontainer\" data-graph-type=\"column\" data-graph-legend-disabled=\"1\">
<caption>Interviews by Month</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Totals</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $stat_logs["count"]; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $stat_logs[$i]["month"] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $stat_logs[$i]["totals"] . "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
echo "</tbody>
echo "</table>
```

OUTPUT

```
Month           Totals
March 2015      7
February 2015   5
January 2015    12
December 2014   18
November 2014   19
October 2014    5
```

I need it to output something like this:

```
Month           Totals
April 2015      0
March 2015      7
February 2015   5
January 2015    12
December 2014   18
November 2014   19
```

Take not that not every month will have interviews so it won't just be the current month (first month)
Any help on how I can get the months with no interviews to show up on the list would be great.

Comment: You probably want a `month` table that has Jan-Dec and then JOIN in the query.  Though that may be messy if the current `month` column contains the year as well.

Comment: So you are interested past 6 months data including  current month ?

Comment: yes including the current month, Note that the interv_date column is a epoch timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this WAAAAAYYYY too long.  But here's a start...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23389/2

It works perfectly well but it's a bit clunky, with two temp tables.  No hardcoding dates, though!  The tables should actually be temp tables, although sqlfiddle didn't work with temp tables so I made them real tables.

```
-- Get a table with the months of interest in it
SET @RightNow = curdate();
create table LastSixMonths (dateVal datetime);
Insert into LastSixMonths values(@RightNow);
Insert into LastSixMonths values(@RightNow - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
Insert into LastSixMonths values(@RightNow - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);
Insert into LastSixMonths values(@RightNow - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
Insert into LastSixMonths values(@RightNow - INTERVAL 4 MONTH);
Insert into LastSixMonths values(@RightNow - INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

-- Summarize the recent interviews
create table Totals (monthAndYear varchar (20), interviews int);
Insert into Totals
select distinct from_unixtime(intv.interv_date,'%M %Y') as monthAndYear, 
                count(*) 
from interviews intv 
group by from_unixtime(intv.interv_date,'%M %Y')
order by interv_date desc
limit 6

-- Do a left join on recent months and summarized interviews
select date_format(six.dateval, '%M %Y'), 
    IF (interviews IS NULL, 0, Interviews) as totalInterviews
from LastSixMonths six 
left join Totals tot 
    on date_format(six.dateval, '%M %Y') = tot.monthAndYear
order by six.dateval desc
limit 6;
```